# Defining a MouseEventHandler in C#

Tags: c#, mouse, mouseevent, screensaver

I'm trying to define MouseEventHandlers such that the application will exit whenever the mouse is clicked or moved or whenever a key is pressed.  This is my first time using C#, but based on what I found online, I've written the code as follows:

```
     MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(mouseClickedResponse);
     MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(mouseMovedResponse);
     KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(keyResponse);
```

which connects to:

```
private void keyResponse(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void mouseClickedResponse(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void mouseMovedResponse(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (firstCall)     //Keeps the application from exiting immediately
            firstCall = false;
        else Application.Exit();
    }
```

The problem that I'm finding is that while the KeyEventHandler works perfectly, I can move and click the mouse as much as I want to no avail.

This is the sum total of the code that I've written to allow for user control; am I missing something?

Comment: What control are you hooking into?  Also.... terribly obnoxious and strange program behavior IMO.  Just curious; what is the reasoning behind such a... "feature"?

Comment: I'm making a screensaver--I agree that this would be obnoxious under almost any other circumstance, it'd be obnoxious if I DIDN'T do it in this case.  What do you mean by hooking into a control?

Comment: The only logical reason for doing this is to behave like a screensaver; is there a reason you're not just doing that instead? If that's what you're doing, this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963880/c-creating-a-graphical-screensaver) or several others (search this site for `screensaver` with a c# tag).

Comment: Wait, is that a thing that you can do?  How?  Regardless, I still can't get the MouseEventHandler to work, and I'd like to know how to do so or future reference.

Comment: See the link in my last comment, or search this site for `[c#] screensaver`.

Comment: Is the first code block part of your `Form` subclass? If not you should move it there.

Comment: @annonymously Both blocks are in the my `Form` class itself; what effect would it have to move them to a subclass?  What purpose do subclasses serve?

Comment: I meant your class that inherits from `Form`, thus making it a subclass of `Form`.

Comment: @annonymously Ah, I see.  In that case, yes, they're both in my `Form` subclass.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was curious because this is not really how one would normally go about creating a screensaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem--my `Form` was filled with `Panels`, and by moving the code for mouse input over to the panels, everything worked instantly.

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, everything looks good with your code.

One possibility - The `MouseEventHandler` is defined in both the `System.Windows.Input` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventhandler.aspx)) namespace as well as the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventhandler.aspx)).

I believe the one you want is the one in the `Forms` namespace.  Is it possible that you're using the one from the `Input` namespace instead?

Comment: No, I don't believe so.  I tried seeing if `System.Windows.Input` would work better, and it didn't recognize it, telling me I was missing an assembly reference.

Comment: If that's the case, just add a reference to it.  Worth a try, although like I said, my hope was that you were *already* referencing that and switching to `Forms` would fix it.  Still worth a shot though.

Comment: I actually can't find that reference in the list of possible `System` references Visual Studio gives me; the closest I can find is `System.Windows.Input.Manipulations`.  Am I looking in the wrong place, or does Visual Studio Express just not have some bits of .NET?

Comment: `System.Windows.Input` is a WPF namespace, so it won't be available if you're not using WPF.  So that being said... I'm stumped.

Comment: This was my issue -- was resurrecting some old keyboard / mouse hook code from WinForms (the horror!) and moving into WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
private void mouseClickedResponse(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

to:

```
private void mouseClickedResponse(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

It should now work fine.